# How to change colour of navigation drawer section titles

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to change the colour of section titles but I can find any options within the xml nor java as I type. The title is called 'Section' but appears in black hence I cannot see it. How can it be changed to white?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:background="#000000"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.getMenu()
                .findItem(R.id.navigation_item_1)
                .getIcon()
                .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B36305"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

**drawer_view.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Section">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_browncircle"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume, based on the white along the right of your picture, that you are using a `Theme.AppCompat.Light` style theme for you activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Correct. I know it works on `Theme.AppCompat.Dark` but I don't want to alter the theme at all.

Comment: There's no such theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Dark`. What theme are you actually using?

Comment: Well you know what I mean dude. I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subheaders use the `android:textColorSecondary` from your theme for the text color - make sure this is set to a light color (as would be the default for `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`).

Comment: What about using the `android:theme` attribute for the `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`?

Comment: Well, generally you'd use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` if your actual layout is a white background, then style specific things with a dark background (such as your `NavigationView`) with `android:theme="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`

Comment: I already changed the background using `android:background="#000000"`. Can I apply `android:theme="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` without specifying the theme in styles.xml?

Comment: You most certainly can.

Comment: For some reason, I now get this error that I don't know how to fix. Please check my latest screenshot above and zoom into it as necessary.

Comment: You'll need to remove the `android:style/` part - just `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`.

Comment: Getting this error: `String types not allowed (at 'theme' with value 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark').`

Comment: Ah, sorry, should be `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`